# How to specify a default label on a asciidoctor bibliograpy

Tags: asciidoctor

I'm struggling with defining a default label for bibliography entries. The reference displays correctly tough.

```
The ref: <<some-um2>>, default text.

[bibliography]
== Bibliography

[bibliography]

- *[[[some-um2,SOME User Manual2]]]* SOME User Manual, 2017
```

This renders as follows:

> The ref: *SOME User Manual2*, default text.
>
> **Bibliography**
>
> [] SOME User Manual, 2017

How do I fix the empty square brackets on the bibliography entry?

I'm using `asciidoctor-maven-plugin:1.5.5:process-asciidoc (asciidoc-to-docbook)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some experimentation, the following syntax seems to work:

```
The ref: <<some-um2>>, default text.                      

[bibliography]                                            
== Bibliography                                           

[bibliography]                                            

- [[[some-um2,SOME User Manual2]]SOME User Manual77] SOME User Manual, 2017
```

produces:

> The ref: SOME User Manual2, default text.
>
> **Bibliography**
>
> [SOME User Manual77] SOME User Manual, 2017

Comment: chapter-bibliography.xml now contains `<bibliomisc>[<anchor xml:id="some-um2" xreflabel="SOME User Manual2"/>SOME User Manual77] SOME User Manual, 2017</bibliomisc>
`

Comment: Just because I am curious. The reference in the text and in the bibliography have different titles. Doesn't it confuse the reader?

Comment: For demonstration purposes only, to trace usage... SOME = foobar = unspecified.

Answer (score 0):

I think asciidoctor does not like the `*` around the reference. If you remove them it works.

```
The ref: <<some-um2>>, default text.                      

[bibliography]                                            
== Bibliography                                           

[bibliography]                                            

- [[[some-um2,SOME User Manual2]]] SOME User Manual, 2017
```

renders to

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I tried this already, and it failed too. Still no text within the square brackets. The generated output of chapter-bibliography.xml is  `<bibliomisc>[<anchor xml:id="some-um2" xreflabel="SOME User Manual2"/>] SOME User Manual, 2017</bibliomisc>`

Comment: You answer solved your problem? Just accept it. If is still not working you could try to export to html and see how it behaves